Teen girl ends up riding in the back of a semi with a group of young people that are vampires
I saw this movie a few years back, and I liked it but cannot remember the name. It was about an older teen girl. I remember something about her and her mom driving on the freeway and stopping at a diner. I don't remember if the girl gets kidnapped or leaves on her own accord. There was a scene where they were riding around in the back of a semi truck, in one of those round silver milk transporter things, and doing drugs. It ends up that they are vampires or drink blood. 
Anyone know this movie?
More Details:

It was an American made movie
Released in early to mid 2000's
The main girl was blond and reminded me of either Mena Suvari or Chloe Sevigny


Hi! Do you remember the approx. year of release? The country\language? The actors or what they looked like?

It was an American made movie, released in early to mid 2000's. The main girl was blond, reminded me of either Mena Suvari or Chloe Sevigny

Sounds like Octane (AKA Pulse) from 2003 with Madeleine Stowe and Mischa Barton.

Divorced business-bitch Senga Wilson grudgingly drives daughter Nathalie 'Nat' home after a visit to her dad, far away. During a rest-stop, Nat sneaks out with a friend and joins a weird truck-nomadic hippie-like sort of cult, which Senga tails. Its 'father' uses drugs and sex to bind everyone to his bloodthirsty scheme.

The gang is some sort of weird bloodletting cult. Here's the trailer, where you can briefly see the truck:




YESSSSSS that is the name! I remembered it being a one word title that had something to do with driving or cars. Thanks a bunch!
